# Any JS framework for animated pie-charts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm searching a JS/HTML5/CANVAS solution for animating pie charts with different values. I imagine to make it possible to click at one of three years maybe with the effect, that the pie chart is **changing animated**. I haven't found a solution with such a button to switch yet.

Comment: Try amCharts - http://www.amcharts.com/javascript-charts/3d-pie/ Animation is good !

Comment: Thx but i've coded my own solution: http://jsfiddle.net/philippkuehn/jDLux/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok... i thought i've found my solution with sencha charts but it is based on canvas and performs really bad on mobile platforms... here i found a css3 solution and this saved my day! http://ehsankia.com/css3/3.php it's a really nice work! (because of the problem with > 180° angles in css)

Comment: Here is the code of my final solution. it performs really good! http://jsfiddle.net/philippkuehn/jDLux/

Answer (score 1):

Sencha charts is a real good framework for that.

Comment: nice, there is such an option... http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ChartsDemo/examples/chart/Pie.html
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this - http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/921/Cool-HTML5-and-jQuery-Animated-pie-Chart?

What are you using the charts for - what do you want them to look and act like?

Comment: there is no option for animate the change of values. i could init with new values... but not animated :/

Comment: If the pie chart will animate in that way then I'd suggest looking at the code and writing an animate function. Or creating your own via canvas and using setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame

Comment: Canvas is not my thing :) so i hoped for an existing solution. selanac85 posted a really cool framework!

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts has been rated the best and I used it on a corporate level application completely flexible and supports SVG which means the charts work on mobile too.

http://www.highcharts.com/